# How to run a multi language web application server?

Tags: java, php, glassfish

I'm a web application developer and whenever I buy a web hosting for my application I'm either limited by the technologies supported or the amount of resources (heap size for instance) so I have decided to get a VPS and set everything up.

I tried to install apache + mod_php, mod_python etc but I couldn't get the virtual hosts to work, since I'm not really a system administrator I had no clues on how to do it.

Then I tried glass-fish which has the plug-ins functionality, it has pre built extention that you can install from the update tool, which basically offers Jython (and python/Django) and JRuby. I only tried a .py using the cgi module and it didn't seem to be working, I'm not a python or ruby developer but willing to learn one of them and use my VPS to test my apps.

Then I wanted to run PHP which I use often and while searching in the internet I came across this article which suggest using Quercus 
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19798-01/821-1760/giraf/index.html

There is no special setup to be done, just extracting the quercus war file into the server doc root and testing it, which didn't work either.OSo I'm wondering if someone could give me some tips or a guide to follow to set up my multi-technologies application server.

I'm a php and java developer, I want to be at least able to run these 2, python would be an extra.

PS : I'm running a Windows Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

Give apache another go - Googling "apache set up virtual host" should help. It is generally easy to configure, and PHP integrates well. Then, you would install PHP (if you can run the binary installer it takes care of apache configuration and mod_php). Java doesn't need to be installed, since the interpreter exists on the client's computer. Python would be installed similarly to PHP.

Comment: when I said Java I meant Java EE (jsp and servelts) not applets obviously ...